# Why does moving the focus cause didChangeDependencies in flutter

Tags: flutter

I use the following code to move the focus on any page. When I switch the page, the didChangeDependencies and build of the current page will be executed again. Why? How can I prevent it from executing?

```dart
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
```

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text('remove focus'),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Text('next page'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                    return Apage();
                  }));
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have two pages, A and B. I click to trigger the shift focus on page A. At this time, the didChangeDependencies and build of page A will be triggered immediately. Then jump to page B, and then back to page A, At this time didChangeDependencies and build of page A will be executed again. If the focus operation is not performed before the jump, didChangeDependencies and build will not be triggered.

The flutter version I use is 1.17.3

Comment: Could you please share the code of it, where you used FocusNode to move the focus on next page

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I added the question

Comment: what is the use of  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()); in your code?

Comment: On any page, you can close the keyboard that may appear by clicking the blank space. In my example, no input box is written, but even if there is an input box, didChangeDependencies and build will still be automatically triggered